# Class Expressions in R. Use of elements in it

Tags: r, expression, derivative

I am using the deriv function of the package Ryacas. 
The output is an expression. 
I would like to use part of the expression as a function so i can try values on it.

Here is the example

```
s <- expression(2*y*x + 2*y -1*x^2-2*y^2);
a<-deriv(s,c("x","y"));
```

the output is

```
expression({
    .expr1 <- 2 * y
    .expr10 <- 2 * x
    .value <- .expr1 * x + .expr1 - 1 * x^2 - 2 * y^2
    .grad <- array(0, c(length(.value), 2L), list(NULL, c("x", 
        "y")))
    .grad[, "x"] <- .expr1 - .expr10
    .grad[, "y"] <- .expr10 + 2 - 2 * .expr1
    attr(.value, "gradient") <- .grad
    .value
```

I would like to use .grad[, "x"].
The only way to do that is like treating the expression as a list

```
a[[1]][6]
```

But the ouput is a class call.

```
(.grad[, "x"] <- .expr1 - .expr10)()
```

Any help? The idea is to take this output and transform it into function that so i can pass different values to it

Thanks!

Comment: The example in the question is not using Ryacas at all even if Ryacas is loaded since `x` and `y` have not been defined as Ryacas symbols.  Its using the `deriv` function in R itself. Try `demo("Ryacas-Function")` for an example of how to this with Ryacas.  Also try `vignette("Ryacas")` for more info.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry about presenting this incorrectly

Answer (score 3):

The `deriv` function returns an `expression` and you can set it as the body of a function through the `body` function. For instance:

```
     #declare an empty function with the x and y arguments
     myfun<-function(x,y) {}
     #set the body of the function as the object returned by deriv
     body(myfun)<-a
     #call myfun
     myfun(2,3)
     #[1] -4
     #attr(,"gradient")
     #     x  y
     #[1,] 2 -6
```

Comment: Nicola. Thank you! If i want to find the value that minimized the function. Without using a for loop with different values. It is possible to right and inverse function?

Comment: See the `?optim` function to search for a minimum or maximum.